# Confusion in Generalization of Pigeonhole Principle

Tags: discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

I want to ask if this two statements are correct:

1. If N objects are placed into k boxes, then there is at least one box containing at **most** ⌈N/k⌉ objects. (originally the statement  is "at least" ⌈N/k⌉ objects).

and similarly

2)If N objects are placed into k boxes, then there is at least one box containing at **least** ⌊N/k⌋ objects. (originally the statement is "at most" ⌊N/k⌋ objects).

Intuitively, those two statements are correct since each box will get ⌊N/k⌋ object at minimum, and if there is a reminder some of the boxes will get ⌈N/k⌉ objects. I am confused how should I use the generalizations. What do I miss about differences? Are my edited versions correct ?

for proof of statement1:

proof by contradiction:
assume all boxes have ⌈N/k⌉ + 1 objects,

(⌈N/k⌉ + 1)*k > N/k * k = N (contradiction) .

It seems correct but Idk how to interpret this

Comment: Your question is kind of vague; what is the "this" that you "do not know how to interpret?" Do you not understand the proof? I'll point out to you that your own proof is faulty. It is not true that "each box will get $\lfloor N/k \rfloor$ objects at a minimum": I can choose one box to put zero elements in, and then distribute all $n$ objects amongst the remaining $k-1$ boxes.

Comment: It sounds like you have a misunderstanding of what the Pigeonhole Principle says: it says that some box has at least so many items *no matter how you distribute the items in the boxes*. It definitely is not limited only to attempts to distribute the items evenly in the boxes (and if it were it would be much less useful).

Comment: Oh , I totally misunderstand the whole contrxt at the beginning . Thank you for your answer

Comment: @GregMartin I would like to pick your respond as an answer, if you want that can you please copy the answer and write as an "answer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have a misunderstanding of what the Pigeonhole Principle says: It actually says that some box has at least so many items *no matter how you distribute the items in the boxes*. It definitely is not limited only to attempts to distribute the items evenly in the boxes (and if it were it would be much less useful).